# Loop Exit: This operation would block forever (Kafka Producer Python at scrappingHub)

Tags: apache-kafka, scrapy, kafka-producer-api, kafka-python

I was trying to set up a server to server communication using kafka.
My aim is to send data from Scrapping Hub to Python using kafka.

I had Set up a Kafka server over public IP. This will work usually , But after a while (after sending 300 or 500 messages),
sometimes the producer and consumer  fails with the error **"Loop Exit: This operation would block forever"** at producer end followed by **"No Brokers Available"** on consumer end.

Usually there will be 2 producers and 2 consumers each  sending to separate topics, there is only one Topic Partition and one Replication for each the topics.
Currently i have given the below config.

> `num.network.threads=16`
>
> `num.io.threads=16`

All other configurations remains the default.

This is the error I am getting at Producer Side.,

```
    [kafka.producer.sender] Uncaught error in kafka producer I/O thread Less
    Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "/app/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kafka/producer/sender.py", 
line 60, in run
       self.run_once()
     File "/app/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kafka/producer/sender.py", 
       line 147, in run_once
       (self._client.send(node_id, request)
     File "/app/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kafka/client_async.py",
       line 497, in send
       return self._conns[node_id].send(request)
     File "/app/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kafka/conn.py", 
       line 663, in send
       return self._send(request)
     File "/app/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kafka/conn.py", 
        line 682, in _send
       sent_bytes = self._sock.send(data[total_sent:])
     File "/app/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gevent/socket.py", 
       line 443, in send
       self._wait(self._write_event)
     File "/app/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gevent/socket.py", 
       line 300, in _wait
       self.hub.wait(watcher)
     File "/app/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gevent/hub.py", 
       line 348, in wait
       result = waiter.get()
     File "/app/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gevent/hub.py", 
       line 575, in get
       return self.hub.switch()
     File "/app/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gevent/hub.py", 
       line 338, in switch
       return greenlet.switch(self)
    LoopExit: This operation would block forever
```

If I try to reconnect from consumer side hereafter i will get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 9, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  ...
  File "/home/ubuntu/project/kafka_handle/consumer.py", 
  line 80, in __init__
    auto_commit_interval_ms=10000, auto_offset_reset=offset_reset)
  File "/home/.../python2.7/site-packages/kafka/consumer/group.py",
  line 324, in __init__
    self._client = KafkaClient(metrics=self._metrics, **self.config)
  File "/home/.../python2.7/site-packages/kafka/client_async.py", 
  line 221, in __init__
    self.config['api_version'] = self.check_version(timeout=check_timeout)
  File "/home/.../python2.7/site-packages/kafka/client_async.py", 
  line 826, in check_version
    raise Errors.NoBrokersAvailable()
kafka.errors.NoBrokersAvailable: NoBrokersAvailable
```

Comment: is the 300-500 messages entered to the kafka topic? `kafka.errors.NoBrokersAvailable` exception raise when there is no connection to the kafka brokers.